# I draw diagrams, but I see old image on the new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a C# web project. I run it on the local web server.
I draw. I show image as follows:

```
bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("diagram.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("diagram.jpg");
```

I don't see new image. Only old one, which I had after changing image name
(Say, I  change diagram.jpg to diagram2.jpg).
Browser is Firefox.
The design page in C# is simple. Just Image and few TextBoxes on the page.
No UpdatePanel and such.
Something with caching... But how to fight with that...

Comment: You should refresh your web page to see the new content.

Answer (score 1):

> But how to fight with that.

Always use a separate path / name. Pug a GUID somewhere. Simple like that. Different file can not be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `ResolveUrl` does, but try adding a querystring to the image url so that the page always gets a "fresh" file. Something like this:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl(string.Format("diagram.jpg?v={0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternative write the image file as

```
diagram.jpg?ver=2
```

to keep the same image file, but force the browser to update it.

Answer (score 0):

If Image has Same name and URL browser picks the image from the cache and displays the same for faster loading of the pages.

Even if you change the image server side the same cached image is displayed until you clear the cache of the browser. You can use query string to change image url like below.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("diagram.jpg?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
```